# How to convert ruby query into mysql query

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
 Customer.select('email, status_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt').group(:email).having('cnt > 1').update_all(:status_id => 2)
```

above is my ruby query that I want to convert into mysql.

Please Help me. Please save my life.

Thanks

Comment: Questions asking for code should **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: The equivalent SQL is ````update customers set status_id = 2 where id in (select id from (SELECT id, count(*) as cnt FROM customers GROUP BY email HAVING cnt > 1) a_name);```

Answer (score 3):

You can just append .to_sql to the end of your call. That will give you the SQL query.

Comment: getting error : not working

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize you had and update_all at the end. Remove that and it should work, if you just want to retrieve the select query.

Comment: I'm not sure if thats possible. What you could do is to loop over your query results and then write the update statement by hand for each result.

Comment: I just want mysql query for that - because I want to run that query in my mysql console for update that records

Comment: By using ruby, I can but I want to run in mysql console